# Google analytics API list out eventLabels

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics

Im trying to learn google analytics + oAuth2.

The documentation is really confusing, so i figured i'd go ask for help.

I want to list out event labels ordered by visits.

```
$results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id, $from, $today, 'ga:visits',
        array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:source',
        'sort' => '-ga:visits',
        'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
        'max-results' => '100'));

foreach($results as $key => $value)
  {
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
    echo "<br />";
  }
```

I can only list out visits so far:/ Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Playing around with the query explorer might help you get visually what you're looking for before translating it to PHP: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample Query Explorer report that should get you there. Just replace the variables in your code above with the rows in the textboxes:

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253AeventLabel&metrics=ga%253Avisits%252Cga%253AtotalEvents%252Cga%253AuniqueEvents&filters=ga%253Amedium%253D%253Dorganic&start-date=2014-03-10&end-date=2014-03-24&max-results=50